# How can I make IntelliJIdea to import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations from maven rep?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

The whole project is in J2EE 6.

I need the org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations class.

I have inserted the appropriate https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2/2.0 dependency into pom.

```
        ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        .....
```

But IntelliJIdea does not see the appropriate jar after the "Import Changes". (import of the package is red) And I don't see it among the external libraries, too.

When I went into settings-build-Maven-Repositories and tried to update the local repository, it worked. But when I looked into the local rep folder, no common-configuration2 jar could be found.

I can download the jar from the remote repository by hand and the needed package is present in it. But I want IntelliJIdea to load it automatically, as it should.

When I am looking at the pom, all neighbour dependencies have O-with-arrow icon near them (Navigate to dependency usages). And the new one has not such icon. These references head to other poms, that have dependencies as:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Are they necessary? I never used such secondary dependencies during the 5-6 years that I worked with maven and I had no need in them before...

Of course, autoimport does not help, for it merely does Import Changes automatically.

Invalidate Caches/restart does not help, either.

Comment: Did you place it in the correct section. So the regular `dependencies` and not `dependencyManagement`? Please add your full `pom.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Only the main pom of the project has 1000 lines. And there are about 20 of poms. And as I have said, I have inserted the new dependency among old ones. So, it IS inserted in the correct place.

Comment: If it would be correct it would resolve. So either it is in the wrong place, you are running in offline mode or your project is borked.

Comment: It is not offline. Borked = obstructed, according to Google. What do you mean by the borked project? Sorry for my weak English. Without that new addition, the project runs with the server OK, so, definitely, it is not the problem of the project, but rather of the Intellij and how I use it. I am rather lower-intermediate user of IJ.

Comment: Invalid pom, leading to a validation error or it isn't in the place you think it is (maybe wrong project a pom instead of jar project?). What happens if you run from the commandline instead of only the IDE. If that fails as well the dependency is in the wrong location or in the wrong pom.

Comment: Normally all the changes to the dependencies should be picked up automatically right after refreshing the project. Try **disabling all custom plugins** and re-creating project configuration by importing the project anew from the pom file via **File | New | Project from Existing Sources..** and selecting main parent pom.xml file to import from. You can also try deleting the .idea directory and re-importing the project from main pom file. If it doesn't help, please attach the logs (**Help | Compress Logs and Show in..**) and a small sample project to reproduce the issue.